# HTML/CSS: Foundation stylesheet wont link

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to get the foundation framework to link to my HTML page but when I try to use the grid system it does not do anything. I have been looked at a few different tutorials to make sure that I am linking things correctly but I still can not figure out why it wont work. Here is an image of my editor and display side by side. My index.html, css folder, and js folder are all contained within the same directory. [Editor and Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YVdT.png)

[image]

Also attaching my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="device=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-4 columns" style="background-color: lightblue"><p>Why u wont work.</p></div>
      <div class="large-8 collumn" style="background-color: lightsalmon">Not displaying a grid system.</div>
    </div>

    <!-- include before </body> tag -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo, it says `collumn`, should be `column` (or `columns`).

Second, please make sure you're using the proper grid, Foundation 6.4 has 3 grids available: XY (default), Float and Flex.

The code in your sample belongs to the "traditional" Float Grid, while the default grid in this new version (since June 27th) is XY Grid. So you have two options:

1. Change your markup according to the new XY grid (take a look to http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html )
2. Change the framework to use the Float Grid, now this depends on how you downloaded the framework in first place; if you used the precompiled package, you should go to http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/#customizeFoundation to customize (basically just selecting the Float Grid and download a new package); if you used the SASS version, go to `app.scss` remove comment to the line where shows `@include foundation-grid;`, and comment the one with `@include foundation-xy-grid-classes;`, then rebuild framework.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on in your second column. 'large-8 collumn' should read 'large-8 columns' (one less 'l' and one 's').

Instead of

```
<div class="large-8 collumn" style="background-color: lightsalmon">Not displaying a grid system.</div>
```

Have:

```
<div class="large-8 columns" style="background-color: lightsalmon">Not displaying a grid system.</div>
```

For reference, here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/xrMOBJ).

Comment: I had been messing around trying to fix the problem and must have missed that. However when it still displays both elements as block items even with the typo corrected. So the grid system is still unable to be used, is there anything I am doing wrong linking the stylesheets?

Comment: Try opening your Inspector on Google Chrome (ctrl-shift-i I think). I'm not familiar with how to do this on other browsers (f12 maybe???). Anyway, use the inspector's Console to check whether or not your css is loading (you'll see some lines in 'red' color if there's a problem).

Comment: Nice good call, it says the files aren't found. I don't suppose you can see any apparent errors as to why they cant be found? Wait up this is werid it says it cannont find my javascript files but it does have my stylesheet files loading

Comment: Not off-hand. Where-ever the html file is located, there needs to be a css folder directly adjacent to it, and then in there your css files. I don't know the structure of your file system to give you clearer advice than that I'm sorry.