# link to foundation stylesheet seems not to work

Tags: zurb-foundation

I already searched the forum for this (for example: [HTML/CSS: Foundation stylesheet wont link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070758/html-css-foundation-stylesheet-wont-link)) , but there was no answer which helped for my case.

I downloaded the current version of Foundation here:
https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/

Then I put it into my project folder and made a link to it inside my index.html. The link looks like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Foundation/css/foundation.css">
```

Other links to external sources worked.

So I tried out the implementation and copypasted some code from foundations examples, this one:

```
   <div class="card-info info">
     <div class="card-info-label">
       <div class="card-info-label-text">
        FYI
       </div>
      </div>
   <div class="card-info-content">
     <h3 class="lead">Chappie</h3>
      <p>In the near future, crime is patrolled by a mechanized police 
      force. When one police droid, Chappie, is stolen and given new 
     programming, he becomes the first robot with the ability to think 
     and feel for himself.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

However, nothing happens. I just get the strings outputted without any styling, so I guess that the link doesnt work. 
My site is running on angular, could this pose an issue? And if so, why does the other link work but this one not?

Comment: `However, nothing happens. I just get the strings outputted without any styling, so I guess that the link doesnt work. My site is running on angular, could this pose an issue? And if so, why does the other link work but this one not?`

Can you describe this in detail? Did you check the browser console for 404 errors?

Comment: The browserconsole doesnt output any errors.

Comment: So far `card-info-content` and so on are no Foundation classes. Which example did you copy / use?

Comment: I used this example from their homepage:
https://foundation.zurb.com/building-blocks/blocks/card-info.html

@DanielRuf To be precise, its the markup for the infocard with the FYI label (the content is going on about some "chappie"). 
Is the example deprecated?

Comment: Did you add the CSS code from below? There is a SCSS / CSS window on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building blocks to work you have to copy the SCSS / CSS content from the bottom, which you need additionally to the foundation.css file.

[image]

Comment: okay, where do I need to copypaste this? Into the foundation.css file?

Comment: Found it, forget it! But still, where do I need to put it?^^

Comment: I added the full css sourcecode from there to app.css (after trying to add it to foundation.css, where it didn't work so far) and linked it inside my head of the respective website. However, still it doesnt work.

Comment: First you have to load foundation.css and then building block css.